# How to paste image from Firefox?

Tags: feature-request, support, google-chrome, firefox

I can paste images from clipboard into SE posts from within Chrome, but can't do that from within Firefox.

When `Add Image` dialog appears, it says supplementary "(or paste or drag-and-drop)" in Chrome and "(or drag-and-drop)".

Can this feature be enabled in Firefox?

What this feature depends on?